# Converting ntext / text to hex / binary / varbinary

Tags: sql-server

How can i get this query on SQL server? it's cause an error:
This is MySQL version

```
SELECT HEX(c1) FROM t1;
```

This simple example work:

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT CAST('example data' AS VARBINARY) AS Body2
```

But this sql dosnt work.

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP 10 [NewsID]
      ,[upTitle]
      ,[Title]
      ,[Summary]
      ,CAST(Body AS VARBINARY) AS Body2
      ,[LargePic]
      ,[PublishDate]
  FROM [Upgrade_News].[dbo].[News_News]
```

That's give me this error

```
Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
Explicit conversion from data type ntext to varbinary is not allowed.
```

1. I wanna just have hexed column as value. how can i do this on SQL Server?
2. What's the correct functio for HEX and UNHEX data on SQL
   server?

I need to convert `ntext` to HEX data on select. it's not an integer or short string.

Comment: it's not integer it's an string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no direct conversion from `ntext` to `varbinary`, so convert to `nvarchar(max)` first.

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(Body AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS VARBINARY) AS Body2
```

`ntext` was deprecated with SQL2005. Avoid using it if possible.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178158%28v=sql.90%29.aspx